# Any way to force an <img> with uneditable style/attributes to fit width of containing <div>?

Tags: html, css

If I cannot edit the style/tag/attributes of an `img` element, is there any way to force its width to fit a containing `div` or some other parent element?

This is for an email template, so no stylesheets, `<style>` elements, or javascript, etc.

The `img` is dynamically generated by a module which I can't edit, and I want the containing `div` to force it to scale down.

E.g.:

```html
<div>
  <a href="http..." target="_blank">
   <img width="267" height="400" src="https..." >
  </a>
</div>
```

The `a` and `img` are not in my control. Can I `style` the `div` to force the image to render at 200px wide and auto-height, instead of 267px?

Comment: what can you edit then? it seems you can edit *nothing*

Comment: Question edited. I can edit the `div` containing the `img`, but the not the `img` itself.

Comment: if you can edit the div then you can easily add a `<style>` tag where you apply the CSS to the image

Comment: @TemaniAfif What do you mean? What style applied to the div will resize the img?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no. Image tags cannot be altered by the parent. You will need to inject CSS code somewhere somehow. Or alter the code what is generating the `img` tag to have `style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;"`.

Answer (score -1):

```
div a img {
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: This is for an email template, so no stylesheets, `<style>` elements, or javascript, etc.

Comment: So what is going to be inside the div?